# What Happens When You Set A Parent Control's Enabled Property?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, web-controls

I have a container of custom controls each of which have 2 controls in them.  One to display when enabled (i.e. a textbox, or checkbox), and a label to display when disabled.

I've overloaded `Render` like so:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        If Me.Enabled Then
            _item.RenderControl(writer)
        Else
            _display_text.RenderControl(writer)
        End If
    End Sub
```

however, when I set the container, which is a table, to `Enabled = False`, my expected functionality doesn't happen.  Instead I get grayed out textboxes and checkboxes.

What actually happens when you set a parent's `Enabled` property?  My assumption was that it propagated that status down to all its children, but it appears that I'm mistaken.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that your assumption is actually wrong.

If you like (and are extending WebControl, and your container has a runat=server), you could use

```
If NamingContainer.Enabled Then
```

instead of

```
If Me.Enabled Then
```

but properties do not auto propagate down the the tree in asp.

Comment: Do you have a long answer? ;)  Specifically: what, then, is telling my textboxes, et al. to be disabled?